# "su" with error "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication"

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, su, xauth

As root, I'm connecting to a remote host to execute a command. Only "standarduser" has the appropriate id-file and correct .ssh/config, so I'm switching the user first:

```
su standarduser -c 'ssh -x remotehost ./remotecommand'
```

The command works fine, but despite the fact that I used "-x" (disable X11-Forwarding) and having X11Forwards disabled in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, I still get the error message:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

I'm not getting the error message when I'm logged in as "standarduser".

This is quite annoying as I would like to integrate the command in a cron job file. I understand that the error message refers to the wrong authentication of root's .XAuth file, but I'm not even trying to connect via X11.

Why is "ssh -x" not disabling the X11 connection and throwing the error message?

*UPDATE*:
The message only shows when I'm logged in within a screen, when using the command stated above on the local machine itself (without screen), I don't get an error message, so this should be fine with cron, too.

I also started the same command with `-v` and surprisingly got the error message FIRST, even before the status information from SSH:

```
root@localhost:~# su standarduser -c 'ssh -x remotehost ./remotecommand'
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

This led me to the problem itself, it is NOT the `ssh` which is throwing the error message, it's `su`:

```
root@localhost:~# su standarduser -c 'echo Hi'
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Hi
```

Why do I only get this error within `screen`? How can I disable this error message?

Comment: Run the command again and add `-v` to the ssh options, then paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Seems like your root lacks some X11 [magic cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_cookie) in the `.Xauthority`, which your `standarduser` has. Here is how to fix this.

**SHORT VERSION** (thanks to [@Vladimir Panteleev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4830/vladimir-panteleev))

```
standarduser@localhost:~$ sudo xauth add $(xauth list | grep "unix$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -c10-12)")
```

**ORIGINAL LONG VERSION**

To fix things, first detect which display number `standarduser` uses:

```
standarduser@localhost:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:21.0
```

In this case it is `21.0`. Secondly, display `standarduser`'s list of cookies:

```
standarduser@localhost:~$ xauth list
localhost/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  51a3801fd7776704575752f09015c61d
localhost/unix:21  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ba2913f8d9df0ee9eda295cad7b104f
localhost/unix:22  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  22ba6595c270f20f6315c53e27958dfe
localhost/unix:20  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  267f68b51726a8a381cfc10c91783a13
```

The cookie for the `21.0` display is the second in the list and ends with `104f`.

The last thing to do is to add this particular cookie to the root's `.Xauthority`. **Log in as root** and do the following:

```
root@localhost:~$ xauth add localhost/unix:21  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ba2913f8d9df0ee9eda295cad7b104f
```

This is how you can mitigate the `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication` error when you run `su` as a different user in Bash script or `screen`.

Thanks to [this guy](http://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=724) for inspiration.

Comment: Interesting. I tried that, but that didn't work for me either. In my particular case, I can launch almost anything (another xterm, VirtualBox), but I cannot launch gedit (I get the same error). However, if I change to root, then I can launch gedit. I followed the instructions to the letter but nothing. Something else must be amiss.

Comment: @luis.espinal hope someone suggest a solution to your particular problem.

Comment: Works great! I shortened it a little: 1. ``xauth list|grep unix`echo $DISPLAY|cut -c10-12` > /tmp/xauth`` 2. `sudo...` 3. ``xauth add `cat /tmp/xauth` ``

Comment: The long version worked like a charm, but the short version errored on centos with "xauth: (argv):1:  bad "add" command line"

Comment: short version worked for me on centos 7

Comment: The possible reason why short version may not work is a copy-paste procedure. Check if the backticks are copied properly and not get replaced by the quotes characters. This is crucial.

Comment: CentOS seems to take its own red-hattian approach for a lot of things. It's not a surprise that things don't all work the same way.

Comment: worked like magic)

Comment: on Ubuntu 18.04.1 short version works fine.

Comment: You can avoid writing to a file like this:
`sudo sh -c "xauth add $(xauth list | grep unix$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -c10-12)) && xterm-or-whatever..."`

Of course, [@Juan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162675/432450) is simpler

Comment: @DaveAbrahams now it feels like a "longest copy-pasteable command" game, which doesn't help understanding the underlying issue.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter true, but isn't there something to be said, from a security POV, for not writing auth info into a file?

Comment: @DaveAbrahams true, it's better not to save this stuff to a file. Although in this case I'd say it's not that critical for most of people.

Answer (score 59):

An easier solution:

1.- `ssh user@host`

2.- `$ sudo --preserve-env=DISPLAY -s`

3.- `# xauth merge /home/user/.Xauthority`

That’s all

Comment: This sounds promising but a bit incomplete. Would you mind to add info regarding how exactly to set `$DISPLAY` variable? I believe this small addition will cast additional voices to your answer.

Comment: This worked for me, while @TranslucentCloud's answer did not. I originally encountered the problem while trying to run the Android SDK manager as root from the command line FYI.

Comment: This didn't work out of the box for me since `xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist`

Comment: tdc, that's just a warning, not an error, xauth will create the file - if you run the command a second time you won't see it.

Comment: Who needs to learn anything when you can just copy and paste! Thanks! Way easier.

Comment: `xauth: (argv):1:  merge:  unable to open file /home/user/.Xauthority`

Answer (score 9):

My needs were slightly different so I came up with a slightly different solution. I needed the ability to run an X11 app as another user (who is not root). Running CentOS, so I don't have the sweet gksudo tool the lucky dogs with ubuntu have which does the Xauth magic.

I really didn't want to break out some custom scripts just to login, switch user and run an app; that seems a bit superfluous to me.

**Step One:**

Allow $XAUTHORITY to be carried across sudo sessions.

Add this line under the rest of the env_keep statements in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
```

**Step Two:**

Allow your target user the ability to read your .Xauthority (yeah I know, scream SECURITY! all you want). For those who just want the ability to run commands as root, this can be skipped.

The target user shares the same group as me so I just turn on group read permissions:

```
$ chmod g+r user ~/.Xauthority
```

**Step Three:**

CentOS doesn't populate the value of $XAUTHORITY by default. Add a line to your profile (mine is ~/.bash_profile):

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

That's it. No more tweaking. No writing .XML to get PolicyKit to work. No running scripts for each login. No having to sudo twice to copy the xauth. From here on out, you can simply:

```
$ sudo -u user xcalc
```

Works great with MobaXTerm.

Comment: This was just what I needed to solve the problem that I was having with getting VM console on CentOS 7. I actually only needed to do Step Three for my purpose (and, of course, ensure that X11Forwarding was set to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same situation when editing the files under `/etc` on my raspberry pi.

```
sudo -E gvim ~/test.txt
```

worked for me.

I would be happy to learn the downside of doing that (if any). Otherwise it works hasslefree.

Answer (score 2):

Because I frequently root on a root-squashed network file share, none of the above solutions worked for me. (xubuntu 14.04). I put together the following script, which works on my system. It may work on yours. Then again, it may not, but it's free to try...

Assumption is I've ssh'd using the -Y option.

```
#!/bin/bash  
if [[ $DISPLAY =~ localhost(:[[:digit:]]+) ]] ;then
    port=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "Unexpected DISPLAY $DISPLAY"
    exit 1
fi
h=$(hostname)
cookie=$(xauth list|grep $h.*$port)
sudo -i xauth -i add $cookie
sudo -i $*
```

Comment: The line `cookie=$(xauth list|grep $h.*$port)` could match more than intended if $port happens to be part of the cookie value. Safer is: `cookie=$(xauth list) cookie=${c%% *}` or `cookie=$(xauth list |grep $h[^ ]*$port)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution using *logname* .
I have added it to *.bashrc* so it is called automatically.

```
xauth merge /home/`logname`/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fully switch to the target user, i.e. use "`-`" with `su` (`su - standarduser ...`). If not, root's X stuff will be dragged around in environment.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I encountered that error, I had an encrypted user directory.  After calling `ecrypt-mount-private`, it got rid of the error and allowed me to continue X11 forwarding.

To determine if your home folder is encrypted, you can try this (as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146511/how-to-check-if-your-home-folder-and-swap-partition-are-encrypted-using-terminal)): `ls -A /home`.  If you see a `.ecryptfs` folder, then your home directory is probably encrypted, in which case you can try doing the command I put in the start of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A nice one liner:

```
sudo xauth add `xauth list $DISPLAY`
```