# annoying message "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication" while there is no problem at all

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

I'm having an annoying problem.

When I'm logged in to a specific host via SSH, the message

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

occurs three times seemingly random about once a minute. I have no idea where it comes from.

Actually, there is not even any slight problem with X11-forwarding, it works like a charm. But this message keeps appearing and it's driving me crazy.

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of it?

I'm facing the problem no matter where I'm coming from, it happens from my Gnome-Desktop and also from a Windows-system using PuTTY, MobaXterm, Cygwin, whatever.

---

After twiddling some more I found the cause to be a monitoring-agent (check_mk). This checks some runtime-parameters of running tasks, the message appeared every time, when this agent was triggered from the monitoring-system, exactly when PostgreSQL-status is checked. It seems this process tries to open an X11-connection but fails. The message is then spit over into my terminal-session as it tried to use my forwarded X11-session.

Is there a way to disable this message at all?

Comment: Also see [*"su" with error "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication"*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110558/20230)

Answer (score 36):

### Make sure you are not running out of disk space

Run df and make sure you have sufficient disk space, if you are low on disk space remove unnecessary files from your system:

```
$ df -h
```

If there are quotas imposed on the file systems, check that you did not exceed your quota:

```
$ quota -s
```

### Make sure ~/.Xauthority owned by you

Run following command to find ownweship:

```
$ ls -l ~/.Xauthority
```

Run chown and chmod to fix permission problems [replace user:group with your actual username and groupname]:

```
$ chown user:group ~/.Xauthority
$ chmod 0600 ~/.Xauthority
```

### Make sure X11 SSHD Forwarding Enabled

Make sure following line exists in sshd_config file:

```
$ grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Sample output:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

If X11 disabled add following line to sshd_cofing and restart ssh server:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

### Make sure X11 client forwarding enabled

Make sure your local ssh_config has following lines:

```
Host remote-host.com
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Finally, login to remote server and run X11 as follows from your Mac OS X or Linux desktop system:

```
ssh user@remote-host.com
```

Credit for information belongs here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I read that, but as there is actually no problem starting X11-applications those steps were not appliable. 
However, in the meantime I found the cause of the problem and will update now.

Comment: As mentioned, this is not relevant in this case. The problem is not that my attempt to forward an X11-connection fails. The problem is that another user tries to use my X11-Forwarding and that the message is spit over to my active terminal session what I don't want. 
The question is "Is there a way to disable this message at all?".

Comment: I updated my answer for a user that asked for it then removed his comment after. For your question try disabling wall access to all but root(assuming that process isn't being run by user root):$ sudo chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall

$ echo foo | wall

Comment: I issued "mesg n" what supresses wall-messages, but still kept getting those :(

Comment: If that process is executed by root then you would. Root can't be surpressed. If that is the case, create a 'monitor' or whatever user and move the monitoring and such to be executed by that user and then you won't see those messages anymore because it won't be from root.

Comment: Good stuff. Adding ForwardX11 yes to ssh_config was the missing step for me.  Thank you.

Comment: WHICH COMPUTER?? - There's two computers involved here, and it doesn't do much good to tell me to edit files and check settings if you don't mention which of the computers I'm supposed to be doing this on.

Comment: http://wiki.docking.org/index.php/How_to_access_X11_Forwarding_after_becoming_root

Comment: I really hate this error message. xeyes works just fine but trying to get something more complicated to run just prints out this error message with no plain fixing guide.

Answer (score 36):

I had interesting version, **xeyes** and **xlogo** works but **chromium** doesn't.

It was a feature from using snap to install chromium.

Quick fix:

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority 
chromium
```

See more:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709789/12207

Comment: You know when you've hit something when the google results show your own answer time after time.

Answer (score 8):

I had the very same issue and this works for me. 
(**Note**: this is not my solution, but since I strived to find it I repost it here. You can find the original [here](https://gist.github.com/onggunhao/71569fc5ecc3f4dffa60f54d36549909) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412065/ssh-connection-x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication))

#### 1. Log onto remote server

`echo $DISPLAY` This should display your current X11 display

`xauth list` If nothing prints on console, it means ssh did not automatically generate the X11 authorization cookies on the local display properly

#### 2. Add the authorization cookie

`` xauth add $DISPLAY -  `mcookie` `` This adds your display's authorization cookie to the xauth

`xauth list` Check whether your display is added

#### 3. Merge your cookie with your local machine

`xauth nextract ~/xcookie $DISPLAY`

`exit`

On local: `scp user@remote:~/xcookie ~/xcookie`

On local: `xauth nmerge ~/xcookie`

Finally log again in the remote server and it should be resolved.

Comment: `xauth add $DISPLAY -  $(mcookie)` did nothing for me.

Comment: Works like a charm ❤️

Comment: This worked, after also doing this: `export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority`

Answer (score 4):

It could be untrusted X11 forwarding timeout. Using the `ForwardX11Timeout` option with a large timeout may help, as suggested in https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1718 (I got this problem in the past, but IIRC, it disappeared after some upgrade).

Comment: Unfortunately not, also when I explicitly set `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in `/etc/ssh_config`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have SELINUX enforcing, and your home directory is not under the /home directory, that is your problem.   Targeted SELINUX settings assume all user home directories are under /home, so xauth doesn't work correctly because the SELINUX type on your home directory is not correct.  I wish I could recommend a fix, but the one I found did not work.  I set SELINUX to permissive to get around this problem.
Better would be set correct label like:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /home <custom_path>
restorecon -R -v <custom_path>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this answer because none of the other answers here worked, and all seem to highlight unnecessary trouble-shooting steps that will likely mess up your configuration even more. (Another reason for leaving this answer is for my own purposes so I can come back to it when needed.)

If you attach to a `tmux` session while in a `ssh` session and the display doesn't work, it will likely require 2 steps to fix (per terminal.)

### Step 0

Ensure you can actually open X11 applications and forward them to your local machine through `ssh`. This is usually easiest by running a X11 program lightweight is better.) If not make sure you connect with `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X` with either the `X` or `Y` switch, with forwarding enabled in client/server configs. If this fails you simply won't be able to get anything working.

### Step 1

Connect to your `tmux` session, then within the terminal fix your display variable:

```
export DISPLAY="`tmux show-env | sed -n 's/^DISPLAY=//p'`"
```

will fix the display variable. Try launching an X11 app at this point and you might have the error

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

### Step 2

If you have the error above, detach `tmux` so that you are back in the orignal terminal with working display. Then run

```
xauth list
HOSTNAME/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1ab9b57e04236de28b161dd0add5ce59
```

Copy this string, attach `tmux` then add this string using

```
xauth add HOSTNAME/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1ab9b57e04236de28b161dd0add5ce59
```

The string must be copied exactly, without errors. Once this command runs X11 applications should work.

Comment: In Step 1, you can simply do `eval $(tmux show-environment -s)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this and it works for me:

```
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

reference: https://medium.com/@toja/using-x11-apps-in-mac-os-x-c74b304fd128

Answer (score 0):

Install XQuartz on mac if required and login directly with the user.
Example - While installing oracledb I was trying to login with root and then running the command from oracle user after sudo su - oracle.

Login directly with oracle 
ssh -X oracle@hostname

Answer (score 0):

Just run: `unset DISPLAY`
before running aquatone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it was due to a read only file system.